# 変数が定義済みかどうかの判定

Tags: javascript, typescript

たとえば、`data.value` が定義済みかどうかを判定するには

```
if (typeof (data) !== 'undefined' && typeof (data.value) !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('defined:' + data.value);
}
```

という方法があると思いますが、もっと簡潔に記述する方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

質問内容が「変数が定義済みか」なのか「プロパティが定義済みか」なのか、判断に迷うところですが、両方の観点から回答します。

### TypeError

> ```
> if (typeof (data) !== 'undefined' && typeof (data.value) !== 'undefined') {
>     console.log('defined:' + data.value);
> }
> ```

こちらのコードは `data === null` の際に期待通りに動作しません。

```js
var data = null;
typeof (data.value) !== 'undefined'; // TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Null型、Undefined型にはプリミティブラッパーオブジェクトが存在せず、プロパティを持つことが出来ません。

### in 演算子

ご掲示のようなプロトタイプチェーンを含めてプロパティ存在判定を行う場合は**in演算子**を使いますが、**プロパティを持てないUndefined型,Null型は例外**とします。

```js
'use strict';
function hasProperty (object, propertyName) {
  return object != null && propertyName in Object(object);
}

console.log(hasProperty({a: 1}, 'a'));  // true
console.log(hasProperty({a: undefined}, 'a'));  // true
console.log(hasProperty('', 'split'));  // true
console.log(hasProperty(Object.create(null), 'a')); // false
console.log(hasProperty(null, 'a'));   // false
console.log(hasProperty(undefined, 'a')); // false
console.log(hasProperty(data, 'a')); // ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

### ReferenceError

先のコードで分かるように、オブジェクトを格納した変数が未定義である場合は **ReferenceError** となってしまいます。
`ReferenceError` を回避する為には `typeof` 演算子を使用する必要がありますが、`typeof` 演算子を関数化しても関数呼び出し時点で `ReferenceError` が発生してしまいます。
未定義変数に対応するには、**関数呼び出し前**に `typeof` 演算子を使用する必要があります。

```js
'use strict';
function hasProperty (object, propertyName) {
  return object != null && propertyName in Object(object);
}

console.log(typeof data !== 'undefined' && hasProperty(data, 'a')); // false
```

Re: jirolabo さん

Answer (score 0):

継承されたプロパティを除いてよいのであればhasOwnPropertyをつかってみてはどうでしょう

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

こんなかんじではいかがでしょうか？

```js
var data = {};

function checkObject(){
  if (typeof (data) !== 'undefined' && typeof (data.value) !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('(Default)defined:' + data.value);
  }
  
  if ('value' in data) {
      console.log('(object in)defined:' + data.value);
  }
  
  if ( data.hasOwnProperty('value') ){
      console.log('(hasOwnProperty)defined:' + data.value);
  }
}

function setValue(){ data.value = 'test data'; }
function clearValue(){ delete data.value; }
```

```html
<button onclick="checkObject();">check</button><br />
<button onclick="setValue();">set value</button><br />
<button onclick="clearValue();">clear value</button>
```

Comment: 厳密にチェックするなら`typeof`で検査する方がいいと思いますけどね。